# Not able to convert METABASE QUESTIONS to sql query for mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query, nativequery, metabase

I am using metabase as BI tool for our analytics and my current database is in mongodb. I am able to create questions in metabase but when I try to join collections or try to do some complicated operations then I am not able to do that without writing in native query.

Is there any way to write sql queries for mongodb operations in metabase ? Or is there any other way around without using square and curly brackets for native query. And if I try to do with sql I get following error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Since MongoDB is NoSQL you simply can't use SQL.
You can use the MongoDB native query language within Metabase.
Or you can wait for Apache Drill or Apache Spark SQL support:

https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/2157

Both solution would allow you to query MongoDB using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed limitation on metabase. However, I have helped our customer solve similar problems like yours. The software architecture is like this:

Metabase -> [Presto SQL/Trino](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/mongodb.html) -> the data source that does not support SQL

In this design:

- Metabase handles the dashboard part of work.
- Trino translate SQL to
  the query language that the data source can understand.

Note: In our customer's case, the integration really requires certain programming work. It is not a quite trivial job.